# Type 'Observable<never>' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx

How to fix this error
**Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'never'.**

I use ngrx in my angular app.

// auth.effects.ts

```
effectLogInSuccess$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS),
      tap((user) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', user.payload.token);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      })
    ));
```

// auth.actions.ts

```
export const actionLogInSuccess = createAction(
  AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  props<any>()
);
```

Error in console:
[image]

Comment: I don't know what libraries you're using but this is most likely an issue with one of your functions returning `never` due to a conditional return type.

Comment: @sno2 this code is ngrx

Comment: Does it say what line fails?

Comment: Yes, it is ngrx. I attached the screenshot of the error in the console. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @Milena what happens if instead of `any` you define the type that you expect? Something like `{payload: { token : string}}`?

Comment: @ShamPooSham { dispatch: false } has fixed this issue, but I still have the issue with type. I will try, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally an effect has to return an action. If you do not want that, you need to specifiy that by passing `{ dispatch: false }` as second parameter to `createEffect`.

See docs: https://ngrx.io/api/effects/createEffect